# How to find a directional derivative of an implicit function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

it's not my homework, I just want to find out how to find a directional derivative of an implicit function. I know what is a directional derivative and how to find it when I have a function in normal form (I mean like like z=x^2+y....).
$$
xz + yz^2 = 3xy + 3
$$
the point is:
$$
P(1,−1)
$$
and the direction (vector):
$$
u = [1, 1]
$$
Could you give me a formula for this? I know how to compute the derivatives of an implicit function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit differentiation (officially, the Implicit Function Theorem if you rewrite your equation as $F(x,y,z)=0$) allows you to compute the gradient of $z=g(x,y)$, and then you use your usual dot product.

Comment: $$
xz+yz^2-3xy-3=0
$$
and now how to create z=g(x,y)? 
I have no idea how, since there is
$$
z
$$
as well as
$$
z^2
$$
in this equation.

Comment: You said you knew how to find the derivatives of an implicit function. Differentiate implicitly with respect to $x$ and solve for $\partial z/\partial x$, etc., just as you did in single-variable calculus.t

Comment: I know how to find a derivative of an implicit function, I mean:
$$
-\frac{\frac{∂F}{∂x}}{\frac{∂F}{∂y}}
$$
so when I want to find a partial derivative e.g. with respect to x, I do:
$$
\frac{∂z}{∂x}
$$
and is it correct for an implicit function as well?

Comment: Your first fraction gives you $dy/dx$ if you have $F(x,y)=0$. If you have $F(x,y,z)=0$, then $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}\,.$$ If you just do basic "implicit differentiation" as a beginning calculus student would, this is exactly what you get!

Comment: ok, so the partial derivative of this implicit function with respect to x is
$$
-\frac{z-3y}{z^2-3x}
$$
??

Comment: No. Read what I wrote.

Comment: "If you just do basic "implicit differentiation" as a beginning calculus student would, this is exactly what you get!"
do you mean:
$$
\frac{∂z}{∂x} = z-3y
$$
?

Comment: Differentiate the equation with respect to $x$, holding $y$ fixed, and treating $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

LOL that guy wouldn't help you at all, its better if you think of it as like this,

(dz/dx) = -(Fx/Fz) ;this is the standard formula

that is a negative times, the derivative of f wrt x divided by derivative of f wrt to z.

so it would be,

(dz/dx) = -(z+3y)/(x+y*2z)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you improve your answer somewhat? Right now it is pretty hard to read: What is Fx supposed to be, $F(x)$, $\partial_x F$, $F(x) x$?